# Newbie question on volatility surface building

Tags: options, bootstrapping, volatility-surface

I am trying to build a prototype equity volatility surface for pricing european call options, as a way of learning a new programming language that I am looking at.

Is there anything wrong with the following method which I have put together from research:

1. back out Black Scholes vols from quoted options prices (solve BS formula for volatility)
2. fit = do a polynomial regression between BS vols versus vols from a local volatility model
3. apply cubic splines (in two directions) to fitted vols to allow for interpolation where we don't have a vol point

Questions:

1. Does my approach sound reasonable or is it completely stupid?
2. Should i interpolate missing market data before doing this procedure, for missing options quotes? Or should i interpolate the surface vols instead, once I have fitted the IVs? This I see as building the surface. I anticipate further interpolation will be needed for the days between contract expiries, on an adhoc basis if a user requests an IV for a date we don't have on the built surface.
3. Is this volatility surface only good for one day? Tomorrow, do i need to create a new surface to account for the changed inputs (eg. spot)? Or can i somehow roll forward todays surface tomorrow? Or can i simply use todays surface tomorrow?
4. How and when do you apply the no-arbitrage constraints that i have read about. Is it done during the fitting, somehow the fitting must consider the constraints?

Thanks in advance for all pointers. I have not built a volatility surface from scratch before and would appreciate any useful tips.

Comment: Question 2, no. If you were to trade on this, the more frequent you update, the better, as the more accurate representation of the current state of the market you will have. Of course, there needs to be a balance between accuracy and speed.

Comment: Not sure what you are actually doing in your second point. Can you be more specific?

Comment: @Daneel - I am using Dupire vol model to calculate an IV. First i calibrate that model (calculate the coefficients of the quadratic equation) by doing a regression against the black scholes IV numbers backed out from market. Then with the calibrated model i get a new bunch of IVs that are different from the BS ones. This is what i think is called "fitting". Those fitted IVs are the vol surface, the BS ones are discarded.

Comment: What do you mean by 'vols from a local volatility model' in your 2nd step? Note that Dupire's formula tells you the instantaneous volatility of the asset at spot S and time t, it is not a implied volatility for an option.

Comment: @ryc I am thinking that I could sort of minimise the distance between the implied volatility curve and the instantaneous volatility curve from Dupire .. and that new number is a "fitted" volatility curve. Or is this nonsense? Why not just use Dupire to build the surface, and forget the BSIVs? My basic understanding, is that my fitted vol should fall between the bid/ask on each BSIV. So i will use Dupire to get a vol number, then i fit that to the market implied vol to get a third vol number optimally between the other two. I plot this third vol. Btw, I intend to create a new surface every day.

Comment: @ryc I am talking about the vol model of Dumas, Fleming, Whaley (1998) .. not Dupire. Apologies. The remainder of my questions are the same.

Comment: Let me first answer the question why not just use Dupire to build the surface and forget the BSIVs. You cannot calculate an 'Implied volatility' from Dupire's model, because volatility in local volatility models changes along the spot's path (it is not a fixed number), whereas Black Scholes has a fixed volatility so you vary this volatility to match the option's price, which is what implied volatility means. You cannot vary local volatilities (e.g. parallel bump) to match option prices, since Dupire's local volatility model already guarantees a perfect match for all vanilla option prices.

Comment: @ryc https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=7373, I am using Model 3 from there, which if i am not mistaken gives a volatility model which can be fitted to BSIVs. I appreciate this might be a basic way of doing it, I am just trying to get started with this stuff before moving on to stochastics once I am comfortable here.

Comment: From what i read and understand, model 3 is basically a quadratic fit of the local volatility surface. Instead of applying Dupire's forumla to obtain the local volatility surface, the author imposes a quadratic local volatility surface, and estimates its coefficients based on an optimization between real world option prices and option prices priced by the quadratic local volatility model. As the author mentioned on page 4, there is no guarantee that quadratic method (or any other parametric methods) can match real world option prices, unlike Dupire's approach which can guarantee a perfect fit.

Comment: @ryc Thanks for your help and taking the time to read that. As you said, the numbers from the resultant model do not match BSIVs (for known K,T pairs) but they are pretty close. Taking a step back, what is the *point* of this model - is it for interpolation only? Or are the models vol numbers for known (K, T pairs) somehow better than the BSIVs (?), even if we cannot get back to the correct market option price using the model vol in BS. I mean, if the model gives out a smoother surface, could it be considered better than plotting the BSIVs?

Comment: As the author mentioned, Dupire's formula can perfectly fit option prices but it can be an overfit potentially. So instead of using Dupire's formula (which is a non-parametric approach completely relying on observed option quotes) to construct the local volatility surface, author uses a parametric form to describe the local volatility surface, which maybe less prone to overfitting at the expense of not matching observed quotes. The ultimate aim for all these approaches (or any option pricing methods) is to accurately model the dynamics of spot and volatility.

Comment: BSIVs are just market quotes converted into a equivalent volatility in the BlackScholes world. Say bid/ask are 90%/92% and my interpolation gives 91.2%, i won't say 91.2% is better than 90% or 92%, 91.2% is just a fair value that you estimate based on an interpolation /parametrization of the implied volatility surface (Cubic Spline/SVI/etc), while 90%and 92% are prices that you can actually trade on.

Comment: @ryc So what does it mean to "fit" the model to the surface then? Is it not to find a least squares fit between the model curve and the implied vol curve (repeat per slice)?

Comment: Yes, say for a quadratic fit, you can do a least squares fit to minimize the error between the model and market prices. For Dupire's formula, it does not need such optimization also, since it is derived from the fokker planck equation, but of course you need a arbitrage free implied volatility surface to start with.

Comment: @ryc So my approach sounds OK for a first attempt? Does my idea about using cubic splines to interpolate the vol surface for the user, if they ask for a volatility value for a date we did not fit for sound OK? Where do we apply the no-arb constraints? During the fit?

Comment: Yes cubic spline interpolation of implied volatility surface is a common approach. just beware of arbitrage (butterfly/calendar/call spread/..)

Comment: @ryc How do you avoid arbitrage typically? I could see how to put the no-arb constraints into the fit function. So we would only ever generate a surface that has no-arb satisifed, or we would generate the nearest such surface within a tolerance, or we would fail to generate the surface. But interpolation screws that up. Unless, its standard to refit the surface as part of interpolation, in order to preserve no-arb constraints, but  i guess this would be slow. Do you know how people typically handle no-arb constraints?

Answer (score 1):

1. Interpolate after building the surface.  Won't your step #2 do this for you, do you really need step #3?
2. Definitely it changes every day.  Look up "sticky strike" and "sticky delta" if you want to see how you can use a vol surface on a previous day as an approximation, if you don't have a fresher one.

Comment: William - Step two only generates IVs for the points which i already had. ie. The pairs (strike, expiry). So for the days in between two contract expiries, we do not have an IV. If the user of the surface wants an IV for a date we have not considered during surface generation, then we need to interpolate. For that, i was planning on using cubic splines, since they give a nice curve that looks like a smile, sort of.